# ionic 4 twitter login getting Error: Failed login session

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, twitter-login

I am getting error in login with twitter for ionic 4 and i am using below function for twitter login:

this.twitter.login().then(onSuccess, onError);

Also i added keys in config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml files.

Getting Error: "Failed login session"

Comment: I resolved this issue.

Comment: hello, can you help me about this